# Can we put blocks in blocks in CSS?

Tags: html, css, visual-web-developer

I'm new in CSS and I have a question about blocks (actually I don't know how do we name the 'blocks' like `#my-id{color: yellow}` so if you can also answer that it would be great)

So, I wanted to know if it was possible to specifie how will type of a class comport, it would look like this:

```css
.my-class{
   h1{
      color: yellow;
     }
   p{
      color: blue;
    }
}
```

I hope you understood what I want to explain, so please answer my two questions!!!

Comment: Using https://sass-lang.com/ Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes, but not when both blocks are rule sets. (e.g. you can put a rule set inside a media query).

Some other languages, such as SCSS, which can be transpiled to CSS, allow you to do that, but in CSS it is just invalid.

Comment: in the near future it will be valid: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2701#issuecomment-402660723

Comment: @TemaniAfif — At some point in the future it might be valid. Agreeing to create an Editor's Draft is a long, long way from being a complete, implemented specification.

Comment: there is a draft: https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-nesting/ ... by the way, my comment was more for users who will see this answer in 5 years so they understand that things have evolved and this answer *was* correct in 2020.